# Syntax error while using xlrd to extract a worksheet in excel

Tags: python, syntax

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("c01_3_3_1995.xls")
>>> worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
>>> for worksheet_name in worksheets:
...     worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_3.3.5)
```

So I'm following along most of the codes I've seen on the internet for extracting a worksheet, but whenever I call for the worksheet named "3.3.5", I always get a syntax error connected to the middle 3 in line (5). Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the name `worksheet_3.3.5`?

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around strings like `"worksheet_3.3.5"`. Without the quotes, Python tries to interpret `worksheet_3.3.5` *as Python code.*

So the reason you're getting a syntax error is that you're asking for attribute `.5` of attribute `.3` of the object `worksheet_3`. Neither `.3` nor `.5` is a valid attribute name; all identifier names in Python must begin with a letter. (I don't see any definition of `worksheet_3` either, so even if you didn't have the syntax errors, you'd get a `NameError`.)